# Calculate equal distance between lines and points

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I do something like this?:

> Consider the lines of k: x = 4 and l: y = 4x + 2, and the point A (0,
>   6). What is the equation of the parabola 'p' with focus 'A' and directive k? And calculate the coordinates of the points on line l that have equal distances
>   to A and k.

Comment: Check the definition of the parabola.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes, I know the parabole has the equal distance to A and k, but how do I get to the formula?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(X,Y)$ be a point on the parabola, by the definition of parabola, you'll have
$$\sqrt{(X-0)^2+(Y-6)^2}=|4-X|$$
Then, you can get what you want by squaring and simplifying the equation above.

Another way : Since the apex is $(2,6)$, 
$$(y-6)^2=4\cdot (-2)\cdot (x-2).$$

This is because if the focus is $(p,0)$ and the directrix is $x=-p$, then the parabola can be represented as
$$y^2=4px.$$